# Can I use when right after that?

Tags: sentence-construction

Is this sentence correct? Especially the part that when..

> Many Mothers can confirm `that when` their kids  grow, they want to be
>   mostly in the kitchen.

Comment: Why do you think it may be incorrect?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can. It's fine. I suggest that you have a look at [That-clause](https://www.englishgrammar.org/thatclause-noun-clause/) if you have the time.
In short, you used a noun [clause](http://www.grammar-monster.com/glossary/clause.htm) (`when their kids... in the kitchen`) which was an objective of the verb *confirm*. They are separate things.

Answer (score 1):

You are parsing it wrong.  The subordinate clause is "when their kids grow, they want to be mostly in the kitchen",  subordinated by the word "that.

The clause "their kids grow" is subordinate to the first clause, subordinated by the word "when".

Perhaps rearranging it would make it clearer:

> Many mothers can confirm that they want to be mostly in the kitchen when their kids grow.

Comment: And if I want to turn the sentences for different meaning: Many mothers can confirm that their kids want to be mostly in the kitchen, when they grow up. Is it ok?

Comment: That's grammatically OK, but "when a child grows up", he is over 18 or 21 years, and probably _not_ hanging around the kitchen.  If you mean later in childhood, you should say, "when they grow older".

Comment: And what if I just use when they grow?

Comment: Kids are always growing.  What are you trying to convey?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to rearrange or paraphrase your sentence, it's okay to just put another comma after "that," making "when their kids grow" parenthetical. Though you'll say it as if you just remembered it.